# Collecting treasury resources when storage is full?

Tags: clash-of-clans

What happens if I collect resources from treasury of clan castle if my storage is full? What happens to the remaining resource?

Comment: The amount that couldn't be stored in your deposits will be kept in the clan castle. 
If you doesn't have room at all, in any storage, a red message will appear saying that your deposits are full.